# Yodlee FastLink "Show Credentials" Link

Tags: yodlee

Is there a way to hide the "show credentials" anchor in Yodlee FastLink? The attached image shows the link I am talking about.

[image: Image with anchor circled]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to hide that button. It's a configuration which Yodlee has to do at their end. Please reach out to the customer support team and they will help you in getting rid of the "Show Credentials" link.